# What are my options for remotely updating xml data files in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

Currently, I package small xml data files with my app. My app loads the data from these files into longlistselectors.   What are my options for not having to submit an app update each time I want to add some content to the xml data files?

These files are very small, so I dont know if I can host them some where and have the app read from them.  Or if I can actually update the xml files remotely some how.

I dont know the first thing about accomplishing any of this so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely host your files somewhere and release your application without any files.

Here's what you have to do:

- Create a barebones CDN (Content delivery network). When I say barebones, I mean literally just have an interface where the user could select which "list/file" to download (from your remote server)
- When a list is selected do an [http get request](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Making_a_HTTP_request_and_listening_its_completion_in_Windows_Phone) for your file.
- When you receive your XML content, write out the entire stream onto disk, at the exact place where you expect to read it from.
- When reading the new files remember to use [Isolated Storage Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Resource Stream, as resource stream only reads files packaged with the .xap file.
- This will allow you to do one release and for every new list you want to give your user you just add a new file onto the server :)

Now you might ask, how will my application update the UI when a new file is uploaded. Well I assume that your main UI (which is linked to your xml lists) is also read in from a list of some kind (and not hard coded). If it is then making your UI dynamic is easy :). Just place your list on your server as well and whenever the application starts up, you check if your list has changed by using a check sum or hash comparison. If it has changed, update it and then render your new UI from the newly updated list. I assume you are an awesome OO software developer and your code is easy to modify. This would in theory not require any modification to your application, just add more functionality on top of it.

I hope this helps, I have done this before so it is quite possible and a trivial task if it only involves requesting xml content and writing it to disk.

Goodluck